# Does calling std::terminate violate noexcept?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function which may call `std::terminate`:

```
int my_fun(int i) noexcept {
  if(i==0) std::terminate();
  return 3/i;
}
```

Am I allowed to declare this `noexcept`? Nothing is 'thrown' as far as I can tell...

Comment: [`terminate` itself is `noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate), so I think you're good!

Comment: Great, thanks! If you wanted to make this an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct and can safely define your function [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler).

The function [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) itself is `noexcept` and does not throw anything. It just terminates your program, and your program will never reach the return statement or reach the end of the function scope.
As the behaviour of `std::terminate()` can be overridden with  [`std::terminate_handler`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler), it is [advised](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate#Notes) to use [`std::abort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) instead, to ensure proper abortion of your program.

If you *would* invoke a function that throws an exception, this would be checked at the end of your function scope, in which [it will terminate your program](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Explanation).

Answer (score 4):

The effect of specifying `noexcept` is that you declared the method to not throw. In other words, it is a non-throwing function. When an excpetion is thrown nevertheless then `std::terminate` is called. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec):

> Non-throwing functions are permitted to call potentially-throwing functions. Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler encounters the outermost block of a non-throwing function, the function `std::terminate` or `std::unexpected` (until C++17) is called:

Hence, you could even throw an exception in `my_fun`, it would call `std::terminate` as well. `noexcept` just means that the exception will not travel up the call stack from `my_fun`.